# Python cv2 MSER not working

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed `cv2` (`opencv-3.0.0`) on my Windows machine, but unable to access MSER class:

```
import cv2
cv2.MSER()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MSER'
```

For `cv2` installation, I downloaded and extracted `opencv-3.0.0.0.exe` and then copied `cv2.pyd` to Ananconda sitepackage directory.

I see couple of post on internet about using `cv2.MSER`, but I can't figure out what is the issue with my `cv2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was refering opencv-2.4 way of using MSER. From opencv-3.0.0 documentation, it appears that I need to use following:

cv2.MSER_create()

Answer (score 1):

```
cam = video.create_capture(video_src)
mser = cv2.MSER_create()
while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    vis = img.copy()

    regions = mser.detectRegions(gray, None)
```